# stuck with this for last 3 days.What can be the solution?

Tags: android, react-native

npm version 6.14.4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-camera: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: have you tried to remove and reinstall node modules (`rm -rf node modules && yarn`) and to clean android build (`cd android && ./gradlew clean`)

Comment: What have you tried? I would delete node-modules, npm install, delete the build folders, try updating RN Camera, pod clean / pod install on iOS.

Comment: Post your package.json

Comment: Please post the gradle build files for more clarification. Thank you.